# Lucene stop phrases filter

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to write a filter for Lucene, similar to StopWordsFilter (thus implementing TokenFilter), but I need to remove phrases (sequence of tokens) instead of words.

The "stop phrases" are represented themselves as a sequence of tokens: punctuation is not considered.

I think I need to do some kind of buffering of the tokens in the token stream, and when a full phrase is matched, I discard all tokens in the buffer.

What would be the best approach to implements a "stop phrases" filter given a stream of words like Lucene's TokenStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In this thread](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Lucene-2-9-0-PROBLEM-TokenStream-API-incrementToken-captureState-restoreState-cannot-implement-a-quo-td562595.html) I was given a solution: use Lucene's CachingTokenFilter as a starting point:

That solution was actually the right way to go.

EDIT: I fixed the dead link. Here is a transcript of the thread.

MY QUESTION:

I'm trying to implement a "stop phrases filter" with the new TokenStream 
API.

I would like to be able to peek into N tokens ahead, see if the current 
token + N subsequent tokens match a "stop phrase" (the set of stop phrases 
are saved in a HashSet), then discard all these tokens when they match a 
stop phrase, or keep them all if they don't match.

For this purpose I would like to use captureState() and then restoreState() 
to get back to the starting point of the stream.

I tried many combinations of these API. My last attempt is in the code 
below, which doesn't work.

```
    static private HashSet<String> m_stop_phrases = new HashSet<String>(); 
    static private int m_max_stop_phrase_length = 0; 
... 
    public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException { 
        if (!input.incrementToken()) 
            return false; 
        Stack<State> stateStack = new Stack<State>(); 
        StringBuilder match_string_builder = new StringBuilder(); 
        int skippedPositions = 0; 
        boolean is_next_token = true; 
        while (is_next_token && match_string_builder.length() < m_max_stop_phrase_length) { 
            if (match_string_builder.length() > 0) 
                match_string_builder.append(" "); 
            match_string_builder.append(termAtt.term()); 
            skippedPositions += posIncrAtt.getPositionIncrement(); 
            stateStack.push(captureState()); 
            is_next_token = input.incrementToken(); 
            if (m_stop_phrases.contains(match_string_builder.toString())) { 
              // Stop phrase is found: skip the number of tokens 
              // without restoring the state 
              posIncrAtt.setPositionIncrement(posIncrAtt.getPositionIncrement() + skippedPositions); 
              return is_next_token; 
            } 
        } 
        // No stop phrase found: restore the stream 
        while (!stateStack.empty()) 
            restoreState(stateStack.pop()); 
        return true; 
    }
```

Which is the correct direction I should look into to implement my "stop 
phrases" filter?

CORRECT ANSWER:

restoreState only restores the token contents, not the complete stream. So 
you cannot roll back the token stream (and this was also not possible with 
the old API). The while loop at the end of you code is not working as you 
exspect because of this. You may use CachingTokenFilter, which can be reset 
and consumed again, as a source for further work.

Comment: that's reason why link answers are bad. Link is dead right now.

Comment: @Mysterion fixed the dead link and reported a transcript of the thread content to avoid future problems with the link.

Answer (score 0):

You'll really have to write your own Analyzer, I should think, since whether or not some sequence of words is a "phrase" is dependent on cues, such as punctuation, that are not available after tokenization.

Comment: Actually punctuation can be discarded: I need to match phrases which can themselves be described as word tokens